# CMake on Cygwin with clang not creating expected dll.a

Tags: dll, cmake, cygwin, shared-libraries, clang

I'm building a shared library and an application using that lib on Cygwin. With GCC CMake creates a `.dll.a` to use when linking. Switching to `clang` I get

```
[ 34%] Built target xxx_shared
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'src/libxxx.dll.a', needed by 'xxx.exe'.  Stop.
```

Is this a bug in the clang CMake extension?

I'm using `cmake --version` 3.3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it seems to be a bug in CMake. Running `make VERBOSE=1` reveals that with GCC:

```
/usr/bin/c++.exe         -g -shared -Wl,--enable-auto-import -o XXX -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lstdc++ -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32
```

while with clang:

```
 /usr/bin/clang++ -fPIC -g -shared                          -o XXX -Wl,-Bstatic -lm -Wl,-Bdynamic -lstdc++ -lcygwin -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32
```

So it seems that somehow clang++ does not get the `-Wl,--enable-auto-import` flag. Manually running the corrected clang++ command correctly creates the expected `.dll.a` allowing the rest of the build to proceed as expected.

Haven't figured out why this happens yet, though. At this point I can't decipher CMakes platform extensions, which seems to set this for GCC.

Update: I've reported this [here](https://cmake.org/Bug/view.php?id=16078).